# MAGMI for multiple web sites

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9, magmi

I have 10 Magento web sites with same content by with different domain and different templates. All the 10 web sites has the same products.

I want to update the products from single GUI for all the web sites. with MAGMI can i do this.

appreciate your advise

Comment: Niranga, how about accepting or commenting on the answers to the questions you post on Stack Overflow?

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Since you are using the same products for all shops you will import the product to the website called `admin`.

```
websites,sku,price
admin,T14,9.99
```

Once the products are imported you will use the Magento admin as normal. You can see the effects of setting the value to `admin`. All websites are selected:

[image: Shows all websites are selected]

Note: *Websites* are at the top most hierarchy in Magento. If your shops are created as *websites* rather than *store views* then you can also control which products can be sold on which shops.

```
websites,sku,price
admin,T14,9.99
"x,y",T15,9.99
```

In the above example T15 is only available on shop x and y.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. but these 10 web sites are in different domains. so i wont able to differentiate by the web site name

Comment: That doesn't matter to Magmi. You can run any number of different sites on one installation of Magento and Magmi just needs to know which site has which code. @NirangaJayakody

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns. my csv not working : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg

Comment: AFAIK [image import](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor) follows your `store` and `websites` column values